# ¿Cómo dar estilos a elementos de la librería Swiperjs?

Tags: html, css, angular, npm, swiper

Estoy trabajando en Angular y estoy tratando de darle estilos a elementos de la libreria Swiper pero no logro hacer que se implementen. He asignado `clases`, `ID`, he seleccionado la misma `etiqueta`, he asignado el `!important` y nada. El `.swiper` si he podido manipularlo pero lo que son las `listas` no.

HTML:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-12" id="text-sec-1">
    <h1 class="text-center">Explorar real mundo virtual con <span class="text-teycorp">Teycorp</span>.</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="col-12" id="img-sect-1">
    <img src="../../../assets/img/sec1/GameWorld.svg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="col-12" id="herramientas">
    <div class="expanding-collection" id="content">

      <!-- Slider main container -->
      <swiper
      #swiper

      [slidesPerView]="2"
      [spaceBetween]="10"
      [pagination]="{ clickable: true }"
      [navigation]="true"
      [grabCursor]="true"

      class="mySwiper"
      >
        <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 1</ng-template>
        <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 2</ng-template>
        <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 3</ng-template>
      </swiper>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;

  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  align-items: center !important;
  text-align: center !important;

}
.swiper-slide{
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí una solución.

Cuando hice mi pregunta no me dejó añadir el TS, espero que esta vez me lo permita.

En el TS hay que hacer un encapsulado [saber más sobre el encapsulado](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation) para eso hay que importar `ViewEncapsulation` y implementar en el `decorador` del componente el `ViewEncapsulation.None` para poder hacer una manipulación de estilos de manera Global.

Archivo TS:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

import Swiper, { Pagination, Virtual } from 'swiper';
import SwiperCore, { SwiperOptions, Navigation } from 'swiper';
SwiperCore.use([Virtual, Navigation]);


@Component({
  selector: 'app-section1',
  templateUrl: './section1.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './section1.component.scss',
    './section1.component.css',
  ],

  // Esto es necesario para manipular Swiper en CSS
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class Section1Component implements OnInit {



  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```